# Dash board and radio screen flashing

Tags: electrical, saturn, emergency-brakes

I have a 2004 Saturn stick shift. When I go to put on the e-brake, my dash and my radio screen start blinking really fast. If I put on my right blinker, it doesn't blink but if i put on my left one it works fine. I take of the e-brake and everything is kinda fine. While driving down the road my car will start blinking off and on home from work 27 miles. I had the battery tested and alternator all fine. What might the issue be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which model Saturn? Also, sometimes batteries test good, even when they're not. How old is the battery? But, this sounds like a broken wire / cable.